# Text over image jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make text appear **on** an image when you hover over it. I've tried a few different ways but none seem to work, or work reliably. I am writing my code in HTML with jQuery, please show me what to do! :D

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').css('height', '150px');
  $('img').css('width', '150px');
  $('img').css('padding', '10px');
  $('img').css('border-radius', '30px');
  $('#container').css('width', '1040px');
  $('#container').css('margin-left', 'auto');
  $('#container').css('margin-right', 'auto');
})

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').click(function() {
    $('#container').append("<p>It worked chaps</p>");
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="gallery">
    <div id="container">
      <img src="http://i4.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article2106793.ece/alternates/s2197/Fluffy-White-dog.jpg">
      <img src="http://i4.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article2106793.ece/alternates/s2197/Fluffy-White-dog.jpg">
      <img src="http://i4.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article2106793.ece/alternates/s2197/Fluffy-White-dog.jpg">
      <img src="http://i4.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article2106793.ece/alternates/s2197/Fluffy-White-dog.jpg">
      <img src="http://i4.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article2106793.ece/alternates/s2197/Fluffy-White-dog.jpg">
      <img src="http://i4.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article2106793.ece/alternates/s2197/Fluffy-White-dog.jpg">
      <img src="http://i4.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article2106793.ece/alternates/s2197/Fluffy-White-dog.jpg">
      <img src="http://i4.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article2106793.ece/alternates/s2197/Fluffy-White-dog.jpg">
      <p>It worked</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please enlighten me: why use jquery when you can use css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it out: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m2mLL14L/1/)**

```
$("img").hover( function(){
    $(".hover").show().offset($(this).offset());
}, function(){
    $(".hover").hide();
});
```

This will make element with class  hover appear over any image when hovering.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are doing this with jQuery, you should do it with CSS.

I'll give you a basic example. Html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<img src="http://i4.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article2106793.ece/alternates/s2197/Fluffy-White-dog.jpg"/>
<div class="text">Here is the text</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
img {
    width: 300px;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.text {
    position: absolute;   
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}

.wrapper:hover .text {
    display: block;
}
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c32jud6j/

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="imgWrap">
    <img src="http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/img/caption4.jpg" alt="polaroid" />
    <p class="imgDescription">This image looks super neat.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imgWrap {
    position: relative;
 }

.imgDescription {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: #fff;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

.imgWrap:hover .imgDescription {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Try it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lyxqd0h1/)